# Why same font style show different on windows and linux by QT

Tags: c++, qt

I do not use linux x11 windows system, and keep same font family on these two OS, and turn the text to image then save it.I use tahoma.ttf font in QT,set styleStrategy to NoAntialias  and set font point size to 7, but on windows [image]

"e""a" looks pretty good on windos.

But on linux :[image]

I am pretty sure the font size is same, because if set pointsize to 8, e will cost 5x6 pixel.
I try the freetype lib on windows not using QT. The result is almost the same with QT in window, so I wonder how to make text the same with windows style.

It looks like that QT 4.7.4 have did included freetype lib, and I try the freetype interface in Qt lib, it shows the same effect with original no modifed Qt qfontengine_ft.cpp.

Comment: It looks like the Windows font renderer is using the predefined bitmaps from the font file, while the other *tries* to create this small font from the original outlines. There should be an option in FT to render small sizes from bitmaps as well, can you find it?

Comment: @Jongware yeal, I recompile my qt 4.7.4, but find that qt not use freetype and do not compile it at all. I read the configue help and not find any freetype option to add freetype to QT.